# Error running xe sr-create

Tags: linux, virtualization, xen, xenserver

I'm trying to add a new SATA drive (SSD) as a local SR.  XenServer may have seen the drive before, but I don't recall every doing anything with it.  I'm attempting to run this command:

```
xe sr-create content-type=user device-config:device=/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-SATA_OCZ-VERTEX2_3.5OCZ-9G0363DTJ6JSCBJ1 name-label="Local Storage SSD 1" type=ext
```

A new SR appears in XenCenter for a split second (I don't have time to read what it says), then I receive an error:

```
The SR operation cannot be performed because a device underlying the SR is in use by the host.
```

Here's the log from `/var/log/SMlog`, minus the timestamps:

```
lock: creating lock file /var/lock/sm/20d58608-bebb-64a8-0cae-d3d36b3f2d7d/sr
lock: acquired /var/lock/sm/20d58608-bebb-64a8-0cae-d3d36b3f2d7d/sr
sr_create {'sr_uuid': '20d58608-bebb-64a8-0cae-d3d36b3f2d7d', 'subtask_of': 'DummyRef:|7f60f5ae-9a40-6550-f587-c28cbe4c4926|SR.create', 'args': ['0'], 'host_ref': 'OpaqueRef:3d304cee-dac2-2eb3-80d9-6e8a166c1135', 'session_ref': 'OpaqueRef:c5a8fc26-cec6-eeb9-09ed-f36604bdfc77', 'device_config': {'device': '/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-SATA_OCZ-VERTEX2_3.5OCZ-9G0363DTJ6JSCBJ1', 'SRmaster': 'true'}, 'command': 'sr_create', 'sr_ref': 'OpaqueRef:7dd401ca-b41d-b606-6612-3dd3919b0773', 'local_cache_sr': '16cbaddd-05db-11b9-d5f9-5933d3192243'}
['sginfo', '-s', '/dev/sdb']
  pread SUCCESS
['scsi_id', '-g', '-s', '/block/sdb']
  pread SUCCESS
['/usr/sbin/vgs', 'XSLocalEXT-20d58608-bebb-64a8-0cae-d3d36b3f2d7d']
FAILED in util.pread: (rc 5) stdout: '', stderr: '  Volume group "XSLocalEXT-20d58608-bebb-64a8-0cae-d3d36b3f2d7d" not found
'
Raising exception [16, The SR device is currently in use [opterr=Device /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-SATA_OCZ-VERTEX2_3.5OCZ-9G0363DTJ6JSCBJ1 in use, please check your existing SRs for an instance of this device]]
lock: released /var/lock/sm/20d58608-bebb-64a8-0cae-d3d36b3f2d7d/sr
***** generic exception: sr_create: EXCEPTION SR.SROSError, The SR device is currently in use [opterr=Device /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-SATA_OCZ-VERTEX2_3.5OCZ-9G0363DTJ6JSCBJ1 in use, please check your existing SRs for an instance of this device]
  File "/opt/xensource/sm/SRCommand.py", line 106, in run
    return self._run_locked(sr)
  File "/opt/xensource/sm/SRCommand.py", line 153, in _run_locked
    return self._run(sr, target)
  File "/opt/xensource/sm/SRCommand.py", line 278, in _run
    return sr.create(self.params['sr_uuid'], long(self.params['args'][0]))
  File "/opt/xensource/sm/EXTSR", line 188, in create
    lvutil.createVG(self.root, self.vgname)
  File "/opt/xensource/sm/lvutil.py", line 302, in createVG
    opterr=('Device %s in use, please check your existing ' \
  File "/opt/xensource/sm/xs_errors.py", line 49, in __init__
    raise SR.SROSError(errorcode, errormessage)

lock: closed /var/lock/sm/20d58608-bebb-64a8-0cae-d3d36b3f2d7d/sr
```

### Update

I did a fresh install of the latest XenServer release (6.2.0).  The disk was not in the server during the installation.  Thin provisioning (ext3) was used.

After the installation completed, I immediately added the disk and rebooted the server.  I then ran the following command:

```
xe sr-create name-label='Local SSD 1' device-config:device=/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-SATA_OCZ-VERTEX2_3.5OCZ-9G0363DTJ6JSCBJ1 type=ext
```

This resulted in the same error.

Comment: How about the output from `pvdisplay; vgdisplay; lvdisplay; xe pbd-list; xe sr-list; ls -al /dev/disk/by-id; mount`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point, I'm just going to declare the SSD dead.  It's not working with a fresh install.  I know it was working previously, so it's probably not a driver issue.  Time to go SSD shopping.  If you're having a similar problem, test your drive in another machine.

**Update (4 years later):** Yes, the SSD was dead.  Shortly after this answer, pretty much everything I plugged it into wouldn't even acknowledge that there was a device present.  I should note that the error message seems very generic, so if you're coming here from a search engine, it's probably best not to assume that you're in the same situation that I was.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the SCSI id from mpathutil.  See http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX122233 for instructions on how to perform this task.

Comment: Yeah, I did that; no luck.  I even did a fresh install.